# Как сделать [group=][/group]?

Tags: php

В общем делаю скрипт и нужно сделать, чтобы

- для гостя `[group=0]Войти | Регистрация[/group]`,
- для юзера `[group=1]Выйти[/group]`.

Если делать условным оператором:

```
if($_SESSION['session_id'] = '') {echo 'Вход';} else {echo 'Выход';}
```

то это неудобно... Вот нужно сделать, как я сказал выше (с DLE не смог вырезать). Все скрипты на сессиях. (Это не DLE, а самопис.)

Comment: А что там неудобного? обычно в начале скрипта делают проверку авторизации, а дальше <pre>if ($userID > 0) { ?>Log Out<? } else { ?>Log In<? }</pre>

Как вариант - оператор `?:` <pre>echo ($userID > 0) ? 'Log Out' : 'Log In';</pre>

Comment: нужно [group=0~1]

Comment: имхо, завязывайте быдлокодить и переходите к шаблонизаторам и mvc!

Comment: Человек элементарного не знает. Как будто быдлокодить с шаблонизатором намного сложнее)

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать на javascript, к сожалению, кода нет у меня, но примерно делается это так :

На JS делаем :

```
function checkUL() {
 var elem = document.getElementById('touser');
 если (пуста кука) { 
  elem.innerHTML = '[group=0]Войти | Регистрация[/group]';
 } else {
  elem.innerHTML = '[group=1]Выйти[/group]';
 }
}
<body onload="checkUL">
<label id="touser"></label>
</body>
```

Теги сами допишите.

Comment: Нет не то! в [group=0~1]может быть все что угодно![/group]
и нужно через php

Answer (score 1):

Я всегда был за уменьшение нагрузки и ускорение работы, поэтому предложил на JS.
Как вам такой вариант?

```
<?php
function logginedOrNot() {
    switch (empty($_SESSION['session_id'])) :
        case true :
            $answ   =   'no';
            break;
        case flase :
            $answ   =   'yes';
            break;
    endswitch;
    return($answ);
}
?>
```

Comment: Блин я не вижу тут [group=*]

Comment: Вы что делаете?)) это пишется <pre>function logginedOrNot() { return (!empty($_SESSION['session_id']))?'yes':'no';}</pre> Со свитчем естественно будет утяжеление. 

Макар, а вы скажите, где вообще брать то, что в "group="? Откуда это значение?

Answer (score 1):

```
$tpl['group0'] = '[group=0]...[/group]';
$tpl['group1'] = '[group=1]...[/group]';
if($_SESSION['session_id'] = '') {
    echo $tpl['group0'];
} else {
    echo $tpl['group1'];
}
```

ИМХО, хранить куски шаблона в переменных удобнее, так как все они располагаются в одном месте кода.